# Cannot convert String into Integer while getting href from a link using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

I'm trying to parse this website using Ruby and Nokogiri:

Here's my code:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

class StreamsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def updateall
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.own3d.tv/game/League+of+Legends'))

    # Grab all the Live streams from the front page.
    doc.css('div#top_live .VIDEOS-1grid-box').each do |stream|
      s = Stream.new

      # Parse the URL.
      s.url = stream.css('a.small-tn')['href']
    end
  end
end
```

On the `# Parse the URL` bit, I get the error `Cannot convert String to Integer.`

I'm kind of confused on how to use Nokogiri for this simple use case.

How can I get the href attribute of each link inside each `|stream|` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stream.css('a.small-tn')` will return a collection of nodes. So calling `['href']` on the collection isn't going to work since the collection acts as an array, and it thinks you're trying to access an element at a certain index (hence the error).  Rather, you need to decide if you want to iterate through them, or just grab the first:

```
s.url = stream.css('a.small-tn').first['href']
```

If you want to make this a bit more safe, you can check for nils:

```
node = stream.css('a.small-tn').first
s.url = node['href'] if node
```

Or you can use the [`at_css`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_css) helper (as @AJcodez) pointed out, which does the same thing.

Comment: Total guess: you were downvoted because you suggested doing more work than what is required: `.css(...).first` vs `.at_css(...)` or `.at(...)`. IMO, though, answers should only be downvoted if they fail to solve the problem, or they encourage *abominable* programming practices. I personally upvoted @AJcodez's answer instead of yours.

Comment: @Phrogz: _**shrug**_ I appreciate your input on this, but I deliberately wrote my answer to best explain why the problem was occurring.  The various fixes are all easy to implement and do the same thing.  And I did make a mention of `at_css` at the end (was unaware of `at`), after demonstrating what it is that it actually does under the hood.  And I mentioned to check for `nil`s which, although unlikely for <a> tags, can certainly occur.  To each their own...

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `stream.css` returns a [`NodeSet`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html) (like an array) of matches, hence the string can't be converted to an array index.

To get the first match, use `stream.at_css`, which is what I think you want.

Comment: Or don't bother worrying whether it's CSS or XPath and call `at` and let Nokogiri figure out what type of accessor it is.